# Java code returns an empty error message in Eclipse even though the same code works in TextEdit & Terminal (Mac OS)

Tags: java, eclipse

I tried to run the following simple Java code in Eclipse.  There is no indication of a bug.  However, every time I try to run it, it returns an empty error message (see the screenshot).

Pls advise!

```
    public class CallingStringClass2 {
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
    String greeting = "Hello World";
    int n = greeting.length();
    System.out.println("n= " + n);
    String message = new String ("First week of lectures");
    n = message.length();
    System.out.println("n=" + n);
    }
    }
```

[image: Screenshot of the error message]

Comment: What steps are you taking to try and run it?

Comment: The code is fine. Put it in a file called CallingStringClass2.java, right click and use run as> java application. The error may be unrelated to the code.

Comment: Look in the .log file in the workspace .metadata directory to see if there is a more detailed message.

Comment: Many thanks for jumping in quickly.  I clicked around further - and discovered that, when the package under which the Class exists contains other Classes that have errors, Eclipse wants to confirm it's OK to run the correct Class (the one I posted here).  Weirdly, the empty error message I was getting didn't indicate that.  When I applied "Run" to the green circular icon for "main(String[]): void", Eclipse explained all of this.  Previously, I was applying Run to the green icon w/ the big "C" (which normally works...) . The same code did run well in TextEdit/Terminal separately.  Thanks guys!